# Python Changing File path name

Tags: python, file

I want to replace  my folder path  by a string,I am getting an error.
I tried this :

```
a="ram"
my_list.to_csv(r'E:\'+str(a)+'\4\mani.csv' )
```

Comment: What is that error ?

Comment: What error you are getting? Can you please edit your question?

Comment: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: What is the error after correcting the code?

Comment: What exactly you want to do, change file path of a folder that already having a csv file or you want to create a folder and add new csv file or change the folder name of an existing folder and add a csv file in it ?

Answer (score 1):

You made string concatenation mistake. try [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) to avoid such mistakes.

```
import os

a = "ram"
file_path = r'E:\{a}\4\mani.csv'.format(a=a)
directory = os.path.dirname(file_path)
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
my_list.to_csv(file_path)
```

Comment: it is the correct syntax. what is your current error ?

Comment: @saddlepoint: The error might be somewhere else. what do you mean by not working? what is the error? what is input and what is output?

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: That is because there are no folder tree like `E:\ram\4'.

Comment: @saddlepoint add your old_path , may be we can help you if you add more about what you want to do with that to_csv also

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = "ram"
>>> filename = 'mani.csv'
>>> absolute_path = os.path.join('E:', '4', a, filename)
>>> my_list.to_csv(absolute_path)
```

Comment: where is the 4 dude ?

Comment: just use: os.path.join('E:', '4', a, filename) then